# Google Play Developer API Error Rresponses

Tags: android, google-play-developer-api

Hi I am using the Google Play Developer API to verify subscription purchases with my own server. Here is the official documentation for the purchases.subscriptions: get method:

https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions/get#response

The problem is that the documentation only shows the result in case of a successful  execution. There is no listing of error situations. How am I supposed to handle these on my server if I don't know the responses?

Comment: Did you ever find a list of the error responses to the subscriptions REST API?